# Can't receive topic in node

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, primesense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use 3 prime sense sensor in both depth an image mode. Since one USB bus cannot handle the load I'm trying to use two computers. I have setup the network in a way that I think works, but my nodes on one computer can't receive message published on the other. I can see them in rostopic echo every thing is right but node never receives the message. Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131836/can%27t-receive-topic-in-node.../) by [AlphaOne](https://answers.ros.org/users/4021/alphaone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2014-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

have you solved your problem? here is some good doc about that: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup

---

Originally posted by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) with karma: 1001 on 2014-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0